# Socketio: How can i send a single string over to the client

Tags: socket.io

I am trying to send a string to the client like this:

```
 socket.emit("start", "calm");
```

but it is throwing an error, is it because it is not an object ?

Comment: Sending a string in this way is allowed (see https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/) - can you send more of your code? are you sure the socket is connected, not undefined, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing first, you should make sure your socket between server-side and client-side is connect. And register event and function to the socket.

Server-side

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('socket connect' + socket.id);
    // when a client connect to server within socket, server will send hello
    io.emit('newMsg', "hello")

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('socket disconnect');
    })

    // when server receive a message, it will send to all client which connect 
       to the server
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(socket.id +': ' + data.msg);
        var message = {from: socket.id,
                       msg: data.msg
                       }
        io.emit('newMsg', message)
    })
 }
```

Client-side

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect', function (data) {
    console.log(data)
})

socket.on('newMsg', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
}) 

// function could bind on button on client side page, get input and send data
function sendData() {
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
    var text = input[0].value
    var data = { msg:  text }
    socket.emit('data', data)
}
```

open console, the information would show in the console. When sending a message on server-side, could use 'broadcast' instead of 'emit' as well to send the message to other clients except you. Read the doc: [socket.io doc](https://socket.io/docs/)